# jQuery continous back and forth rotation animation

Tags: jquery, animation, rotation

I need some help with this.

I made a nice web kit animation for one of the elements on my site. It is supposed to rotate 7 degrees back and forth continuously.
Unfortunately it works only in Chrome. Here is the code:

```
#brk {
background: url("../images/brk.png");
width: 118px;
height: 54px;
display: block;
position: relative;
top: 65px;
left: 93px;
     -webkit-animation: brk-spin 3s infinite linear;
     -moz-animation: brk-spin 3s infinite linear;
     -o-animation: brk-spin 3s infinite linear;
     -ms-animation: brk-spin 3s infinite linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes brk-spin {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);}
50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);}
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes brk-spin {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);}
50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);}
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
}

@-o-keyframes brk-spin {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);}
50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);}
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
}

@-ms-keyframes brk-spin {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);}
50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);}
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

So I thought I use some jQuery for the browsers that does not support the webkit animation.
I tried many variation, but nothing worked.

I downloaded the jQuery rotate plug in ( https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ )

I tried something like this:

```
<script>
if(!Modernizr.cssanimation) { 
    $(function() {

    $('#brk').stop().rotate({ angle:0, animateTo: 7, duration:600, callback: 

function() {
        $('#brk').stop().rotate({ animateTo: -7, duration:600});
        }
    });

(function roty() {
     setTimeout(function() { roty() },1200);
             })();
       });
}
</script>
```

But whit this the image (div with background) swings only once back and forth and it stops.

Any idea how to make it loop?

Help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `@-webkit-keyframes` works only in Chrome because Chrome uses the WebKit rendering engine (so does Safari, anyway). You can try using [prefixfree.js](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/), or use multiple vendor prefixes in your CSS file.

Comment: Meant to say CSS animation, where only the webkit is working, the others are not. Like  prefixfree - thank you for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have the method call itself?  So have the one that animates to 7 call the other, and vice versa.  Something like this:

```
function rotateSeven() {
    $('#brk').stop().rotate({ angle:0, animateTo: 7, duration:600, callback: function() {
        rotateNegative();
        }
    });
}

function rotateNegative() {
    $('#brk').stop().rotate({ angle:0, animateTo: -7, duration:600, callback: function()  {
        rotateSeven();
        }
    });
}
```

Then when you call one of them, they would continue to call each other.  I'm not sure if this would be the best way to do it though, as I've not tried to animate in the way you are here.

**EDIT**

Do you possibly have an error in your code?  I did something more simple, but it works for me, continuously:

```
function fadeIn() {
    jQuery("#test").fadeIn();
    fadeOut();
}

function fadeOut() {
    jQuery("#test").fadeOut();
    fadeIn();
}

fadeOut();
```

That is a simple example, but it works for me in my [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wPfz/1/)

**EDIT 2**

Here is a working example... Just to make sure, the documentation says to use an IMG tag - your #brk is an IMG tag, right?  Otherwise, try and see what is different in yours compared to mine on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YKj5D/1968/)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: #brk is a div with a background image - but the script works with divs as well!
BTW the script have to be after the div element in order to work. Maybe that was my issue with your first script - as I tried to use it in the <head> tag.
Thank you again, I appreciate you help very much!